ListView.Items(0),Selected error System.nullreferenceexception
I'm trying to debug a program which uses a ListView to create a list of icons for files stored in a DB. I got the log of an exception stating System.nullreferenceexception: 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.
What I get specifically from the log file is this
System.nullreferenceexception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
in System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.set_Selected(Boolean value)
in (MyFilesControl , Boolean ) 
in MyLibrary.MyFilesControl.MyMethod(Boolean MyBooleanVariable)

where MyFilesControl is a custom Control basically used to show a tree view of folders, a file view and other things.
The real problem is that last line in the log seems to imply the error is generated here.
If MyBooleanVariable AndAlso MyListView.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso MyListView.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
    MyListView.Items(0).Selected = True ' error here, most likely
End If

This implies in that last line of code something should be Nothing... Except in theory it CAN'T be nothing. Right? All 3 conditions right above exist (included MyBooleanVariable, since it's an optional Boolean created and passed by MyMethod).
So my main issue and doubt is: can something be Nothing in that last line of code? I also tried to set the value to Nothing but I get the exception on the new added line, that's why I'm assuming a ListItem cannot be Nothing. Asking also because I'm trying to replicate the exception but I seem uncapable of ever getting it. The code always works for me but still that log exists.

There can be a NRE in the .NET code of the set accessor of the Selected property. That's not a simple property but this. It could be for example a threading issue.

"error here, most likely"?? Set a breakpoint and inspect the variables, properties, etc.. Then you will know exactly where. Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio.

@Olivier no, that's the point: i can't ever get the exception so I can't know 100% sure if the error is there. it's the only line that make sense in the code but at the same time i never get the error. I only know by the log that the error can occur. So the main point is: I know that in theory the error is there but how can it be if there can't be a Nothing value?

@TimSchmelter actually I don't understand what the code does but as I see it I can in theory take the hypothesis Selected can return an exception... Only I don't understand how and why others would get this error and I don't. It's difficult to debug something you can't replicate or understand...

@grimoiredark: we just have to gues since we dont know the full code. Is it possible that the program uses tasks or multiple threads which all access the listview?

I don't know. Also, I tried to check the Selected property and tested. As I see, in my current work there's no IsHandleCreated property/function for the ListView class. Maybe an older .NET version? I don't know...
